# Excel—insert underline to separate weeks

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, conditional-formatting

I have an excel worksheet with a column of deadlines. My project managers want an underline added to the last row in a given week to visually separate between weeks. How can I do this without having to manually insert the borders each week?

Comment: Is **Monday** the first day of your workweek??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using conditional formatting without any need for macros.  Select the first row to format, choose 'Conditional Formatting' from the ribbon, then 'New rule...' and 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format'

Use the format button to set an appropriate underline style (by setting the bottom border of the cells).

In the formula box, you need something like this:

```
= WEEKNUM($A2, 1) <> WEEKNUM($A3, 1)
```

You can then use the format painter to copy the conditional formatting to the other rows in your table.

That should work if your dates are in column A and your first row of data is row 2.  If not, you need to adjust the `$A2` and `$A3` accordingly.

The `1` parameter tells `WEEKNUM()` that your week starts on a Sunday.  If you need it to start on a different day, look at the [`WEEKNUM() documentation`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/weeknum-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340) to check which parameter to use.